# LabelledGeneric with differing types

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given these ADTs:

```
case class SourceRecord(name: String, number: Int)
case class TargetRecord(number: Int, name: String)
```

I can easily map from a `SourceRecord` to a `TargetRecord`:

```
val sourceGen = LabelledGeneric[SourceRecord]
val targetGen = LabelledGeneric[TargetRecord]
val sourceRecord = SourceRecord("record_1", 1)
val targetRecord = targetGen.from(sourceGen.to(sourceRecord).align[targetGen.Repr])
```

However I'm struggling to understand how to perform the conversion if I introduce a new type:

```
case class MyNumber(value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class SourceRecord(name: String, number: Int)
case class TargetRecord(number: MyNumber, name: String)

Error: could not find implicit value for parameter align: shapeless.ops.hlist.Align[sourceGen.Repr,targetGen.Repr]
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow provide a type class to align the `Int` to the `MyNumber` but I don't know how. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `Unwrapped` to talk about which types are just "wraps" versus actual types. Beyond that, I'm not sure offhand how much you'll have to reimplement...

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can define it as follows:

```
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Align
import shapeless.record.Record
import shapeless.{::, HNil, Witness}
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

implicit val align: Align[Record.`'name -> String, 'number -> Int`.T, Record.`'number -> MyNumber, 'name -> String`.T] = {
  case s :: (i: FieldType[Witness.`'number`.T, Int]) :: HNil => 'number ->> MyNumber(i) :: 'name ->> s :: HNil
}
```